# Is this photo of a receipt stating "Tip for U.S. citizens only" real?

Tags: immigration

This photo has been making the rounds on facebook.  Was this a legitimate bill being paid?

[image]

Comment: ([Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/tip-non-immigrants/))

Comment: I see no reason to doubt that some rude individual did exactly this at some time, independent of whether this instance was constructed for the photo or not. I do find it interesting that we can't see whether this was the merchant copy or the customer copy.p, which makes me suspect it's not legit.